# Android Navigation Drawer framework issue | Kotlin | 2022

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer in an existing android app using Kotlin. I have created 2 activities. Now I want to implement a Navigation Drawer in each of these activities.
The implementation is quite easy. I am facing issues when I want to add a navigation drawer activity to my application. The code is never compiled. I tried many things. But nothing is working.

The version of my android studio.
[image: Android Studio version]

List of dependencies
[image: Dependecies]

My navigation drawer activity.
[image: My Navigation Drawer Activity]

The monster error.
[image: Here is the monster error]

Please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code: use the code formatting tools available to you to post the code itself.

Comment: @ianhanniballake How to show an error inside code if I am not allowed to use screenshot, sir? pasting code wouldn't show the error,

Comment: All of those windows support copying the text out of them, allowing you to put that text directly in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove** the dependencies `androidx.navigation` without `ktx` at the end and **update** the Kotlin version in the project to at least `1.6.0`.